# Saving a Date in a Coisefield - Django?

Tags: django

so what I'm trying to build is basically a calendar. For this, a user has to choose a beginning date and time for an event as well as an end time. Everything then has to be stored - of course - in the database.

I want to realize that by using a ChoiseField (unless there is a better solution). How would it be possible to generate all the dates of the month in a coisefield since some months are 30 days others have a different length etc.? Same with the hours of a day?

I cant seem to come up with a working approach? How would one approach this problem? suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as two fields:

```
#models.py
class Event(models.Model):     
         start = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
         end = models.DateTimeField()
```

and for calendar (=widget) i would use this or some similar plugin:
https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker

Comment: oh, maybe I expressed myself wrong. I was talking about the form not the model. Any suggestions there?

Comment: The second part of my answer also answers to that question - if you are using bootstrap/jqueryUI, you can surely find some django plugin for integrating this into form.

Comment: @Xen_mar For example, the plugin i linked: https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker is in form used like this:
    `todo = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    date = forms.DateField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
                                       "pickTime": False}))
    reminder = forms.DateTimeField(
        required=False,
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
                                       "pickSeconds": False}))`

Comment: @Xen_mar did you suceed? If yes, could you accept my answer? :)